# Horizontal calendar/datepicker, with tableview underneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

Im building an app, and I need a feature like on the image i attached. Does anyone of you, know of a library that can create something similar, or maybe someone can give me a hint how to create it myself :)

What I need is a horizontal calendar, with a tableview underneath.. I need to be able to swipe left or right in the tableview, and then the date has to change, wither a day forward or a day backwards, unless its on the day of today. Then its not possible to go a day back. Hope it makes sense!

[image: Horizontal Datepicker]

Best regards

Comment: Hi Nicolai. Did you ever manage to do this? Care to share some links? Thanks !

Comment: Hey! Yes, I did.. it takes a collectionview with collectionviews inside. And then when you scroll the top collectionview, and it’s delegate “cellIsDisplaying”-ish fires, you have to tell the bottom collectionview to change index :) hope it makes sense - otherwise let me know, and I’ll try and share some code :)

Comment: The bottom collectionview then has a tableview in each cell btw :) @el-flor